# Can someone explain the math used in this query?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm using a query I found on stackoverflow for finding locations near a given latitude/longitude in a database.  Below is the query.  Entirely out of curiosity, can someone explain what exactly it's doing (the math bits, not the sql)?  44.xxx and -93.xxx is the lat/long to start from.

Thanks!

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * 
acos( cos( radians(44.96577) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-93.268433) ) + sin( radians(44.907411) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM ivr_sign.property 
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance ASC, id ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

This formula uses the [Spherical law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) to calculate the great circle distance between two points, given their latitudes and logitudes.

In particular, it calculates the distance between fixed point (lat $44.\cdots$, long $-93.\cdots$) with the known points in the database.

The 3959 is (an approximation of) the radius of the earth in miles.